# How to use timer in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I would like to send email notifications to users of my project exactly at 8 a.m,
Here we are using a thread to send emails to the user. I would like to send some emails exactly at 8 A.M. How can I execute that perticular logic in this Thread. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The java ScheduledExecutorService should be helpful here.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html